# NameError: name 'googlemaps' is not defined

Tags: python, google-maps

I have been trying to deploy a web application on Heroku using Flask and googlemaps. The app runs locally but when I try deploying it to the server, I get this error on heroku logs: `NameError: name 'googlemaps' is not defined`

Here is what I tried:
Using different import statements for googlemaps in virtual environment
Adding googlemaps==2.4.5 to requirements.txt
Using a different API key

Part of my code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from googlemaps import Client

app = Flask(__name__)  
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key= my_key)

my_distance = gmaps.distance_matrix((start_lat,start_lng),(end_lat,end_lng))
distance = my_distance['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `googlemaps.Client()` by just `Client()`.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line `from googlemaps import Client` to this:

```
import googlemaps
```